# In schematics Design two buses having different names then how their pins can be connected together?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics

[image]I am referring one schematics design of silicon labs in that at page number 3 page title "EFR32 I/O Port Connections". Pin of bus RADIO_PA[5..0] and WSTK_P[45..0] are connected together how it can be possible when both buses are with different names.[Here is the schematics Design link "EFR32MG1"](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/schematic-files/EFR32MG1-BRD4151A-B03-schematic.pdf)

Comment: You can't expect me to start hunting for the spot in the schematic where your are referring to. Draw a circle or arrow. Anyway I suspect that it is just aliasing. That is allowed in most schematic editors

Comment: i have given the image also please have a look

Answer (score 0):

In this schematic, not all signals of the busses are connected. Only those who are connected with single wires, e.g. RADIO_PA0 to WSTK_PA9.

Comment: this is the question how a single wire can be connected with two buses of different names ?

Comment: I do not see any problem in naming one signal with two names. As an example, let‘s consider a house: Its name is „house“ in english and „haus“ in german. So there are two different names for the very same thing.